# Activity layout is not displayed during game loading (starting with Android API 24)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-7.0-nougat

There is game activity in which OpenGL rendering is performed (component app.OGlSurfaceView). While the game is loading,  component textView "Loading..." is displayed on the black screen.

GameActivity.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".activities.GameActivity">

  <app.OGlSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/oglView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:background="@color/black">
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/load_level_text"
      android:text="Loading..."/>
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This works well on Android with API 14-23. But starting from version API 24 (Android 7.0), the load message on black screen does not appear, but continues displayed the layout of MainActivity.xml(until the game loads). Question: how to make a message appear during game loading? I will be grateful for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. Starting with android 7.0 use AsyncTask in MainActivity.

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(view: View) {
    ...
    fun startGameButtonClick() { // start the game
        val layout: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.loading_layout)
        Loading(layout).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
        ...
        val intent = Intent(this, GameActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

AsyncTask.java:

```
public class Loading extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private WeakReference<ConstraintLayout> layout;

    public Loading(ConstraintLayout layout) {
        this.layout = new WeakReference<>(layout);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        layout.get().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // show load message
    }
    ...
}
```